# How to get difference of two lists in Python that do not contain unique elements within the list

Tags: python, list, tuples

If I have the following two lists of tuples in Python:

```
A = [('A',10),('B',20),('C',20)]
B = [('A',3),('C',10)]
```

How can I obtain the following list (A-B), which is effectively the difference of A and B (but it needs to preserve count of the difference):

```
C = [('A',7),('B',20),('C',10)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem already? Have you tried searching for relevant documentation? You could for example check [the documentation for Python data structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Answer (score 1):

The Counter class in the collections module can help you do the kind of thing you have asked about. Documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

However, there are some design choices that would need to be made in a generalized solution to address your question.

For example, if `B` contains ('D', 77) in addition to the items in your question, and `A` has no entry for 'D', then we could either ignore 'D' or treat `A` as having a zero value for 'D' with the resulting "difference" for 'D' shown as -77.

The `-` operator for two Counter objects will ignore 'D', whereas the `subtract()` method for a Counter object will not.

Furthermore, your question specifies output in the form of a list of tuples of string and number. While this spec can be unambiguously met for your example if we replicate the ordering in `A`, it's less clear what to do if `B` were to contain an entry such as 'D' in the example above. For example, should 'D' come before 'C' or after it, or is either OK?

UPDATE: As pointed out by @enke in the comments, `dict` provides the necessary ordering guarantees (as of Python 3.7) to support more condensed logic without explicit iteration in our code.

Here is some code that does exactly what you've asked about, with some further examples illustrating the design considerations above.

```
    def counterDifferences():
        A = [('A',10),('B',20),('C',20)]
        B = [('A',3),('C',10)]
        
        # (1) This does what the question asks how to do, using subtract().
        acount = Counter(dict(A))
        acount.subtract(dict(B))
        C = [*acount.items()] # This works because, as of Python 3.7, dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order.
        print(f"C {C}")
        # C [('A', 7), ('B', 20), ('C', 10)]

        A = [('A',10),('B',20),('C',20)]
        B = [('A',3),('C',10),('D',77)]

        # (2) This shows that operator '-' will give the same result even if B contains keys not found in A.
        C = [*(Counter(dict(A)) - Counter(dict(B))).items()]
        print(f"C {C}")
        # C [('A', 7), ('B', 20), ('C', 10)]

        # (3) This shows that subtract() includes keys in B in addition to keys in A.
        dcount = Counter(dict(A))
        dcount.subtract(Counter(dict(B)))
        D = [*dcount.items()]
        print(f"D {D}")
        # D [('A', 7), ('B', 20), ('C', 10), ('D', -77)]
```

Comment: Instead of all that work, isn't it simpler to convert `A` and `B` to dicts, then pass to `Counter`? So like: `A = Counter(dict(A)); A.subtract(dict(B)); C = [*A.items()]`

Comment: @enke, yep, given the guaranteed preservation of insertion order for `dict` as of Python 3.7, your simpler suggestion works. Edited answer to reflect this.